# Add object as directive property inside for loop AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created Directive :

```
app.directive('gaAirbusImage', function(gaAirbusImgService,$rootScope){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl:'components/airbus/partials/airbusImage.html',
        scope: {
            imgData: '=gaAirbusImgData'
        },
        controller:'GaAirbusController',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.thumbnailSrc = gaAirbusImgService.getThumbnailImageSrc(scope.imgData._links.thumbnail.href);
        }
    };
});
```

I am trying to dinamicaly create more than one gaAirbusImage directive from service file using function:

```
function createImages(images) {
   angular.forEach(images.features,function (feat) {
       var newElement = $compile("<div ga-airbus-image ga-airbus-img-data="+feat+"></div>")($rootScope);
       angular.element(document.getElementById('airbusresults')).append(newElement);
   }
}
```

I want to assign feat object as is, not as [Object object]. I know I am doing string concatenation but how to avoid this ?

Comment: `feat` is an object, access the property you require otherwise you'll need to serialize this object to JSON or some other form.

Comment: Using a service to compile directives and linking them to `$rootScope`  [tangles concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) in a way that will make the app hard to understand, test, debug, and maintain. There is likely a better way.